# Why does WP_Query not search for two 'meta_query' keys separated with OR?

Tags: wp-query, search

I have written a search query using `WP_Query`, where am searching for 2 `meta_query` values like below:

```
$keyword = $_GET['tewa_search'];
$institute_name = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'inistitute_name', TRUE);

$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'messages',
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'key' => 'inistitute_name',
            'value' => [ $institute_name ],
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ],
        [
            //course values stored as ID's like 200, 300 in database
            'key' => 'course',
            //Single course ID if user types 'java' then I can get only single course ID
            'value' => $keyword,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ],
    ],
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_status' => $status,
];
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

While storing the `meta_key` `'course'` if user selects multiple courses then the corresponding course ID's am storing in the database, suppose if user selects 2 courses then am storing 2 course ID's separated with comma(100, 200). While searching, if user enters a course name then I will get the corresponding course ID and then search it with the course Id's stored as course IDs are separated with comma(100, 200, 300).

But my query is not working as expected, can anyone tell me whats wrong in the code?

Comment: I take it from your description that `$_GET['tewa_search']` is an array (multiple courses) ? If yes, then you you should be using `IN` as the `compare` value of your second array in the `meta_query` array

Comment: @Dan., No its not that $_GET['tewa_search'] is not an array of multiple courses. It has only a single course ID, like suppose if user enters a course name 'Java' then I will get the corresponding course ID and compare it with the meta_key 'course' stored as a course string like " 100, 200, 300 " for each post.

Comment: Oh ok. I'm not sure what the issue is, it's difficult to know what you mean by 'it's not working as expected' without knowing more about what you are trying to achieve. Could it be not working as expected because you are doing `OR` instead of `AND` in your meta query

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a solution by making some changes in my code while saving the post I was storing the courses as a string like: " 100, 200, 300 " and If user enters a keyword if that keyword matches with a course then I am getting that corresponding course ID and then using the WP_Query with the following parameters:

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'messages',
    'meta_query' => array (
    'relation' => 'AND',
     array(
            'key' => 'inistitute_name',
            'value' => array ($institute_name),
            'compare' => 'IN'
          ),
    array(
       'key' => 'course', //course values stored as ID's like 200, 300 in database
       'value' => $keyword, //Single course ID if user types 'java' then I can get only single course ID 
       'compare' => 'LIKE'
      )
    ),
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'paged' => $paged,
   'post_status' => $status,
);
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Previously what was the mistake I did is while saving the post I was storing the multiple course names as numeric array itself that causes MySql engine to store that array Serializable string which is difficult to search. But now I am saving the multiple course names as a string separated by commas like this : 123, 456, 789